# How to count the number of the generated PWM pulse on stm32?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, stm32, timer, stm32f4

I have a stepper motor on TIM2 CH1. When a button is pressed the motor runs. How to count the steps(pulse) the PWM generated while the button was pressed?

Comment: You are using Timer 2.  Hint, Hint, Nudge, Wink.....

Answer (score 2):

**Use another timer as a slave to count `TIM2` reloads.**

- Pick a second timer as a slave. Check the description of the `SMCR` register in the Reference Manual to see if it can be slaved to `TIM2`. `TIM5` would be a good choice as it has a 32 bit counter.
- Set `TIM2` as master, trigger output on Update (`MMS` bits in `CR2`). It will generate a trigger output whenever the PWM counter is reloaded.
- Set `TIM5` as slave. First, check the table at the end of the `SMCR` register description. Find `TIM2_TRGO` (the master) in the row corresponding to `TIM5` (the slave). Note the `TS=xxx` setting in the column header, this value goes into the `TS` bits of `SMCR`. Slave Mode (`SMS`) should be External Clock Mode (`111` = `0x07`). Now, `TIM5` will count the reloads of `TIM2`, effectively the PWM cycles.
- Enable the slave (`TIM5`) first, the master (`TIM2`) afterwards.